Pgbackrest point in time restore, database does not start
I use pgBackRest 2.38 for postgresql 13 database backup and restore, I got a strange issue for point-in-time recovery. Once the point-in-time-recovery is done the pgbackrest kick starts postgresql server but it fails with below error
FATAL:  canceling authentication due to timeout
        psql: error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        his probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
 pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
 FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
 HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 40) running in data directory "/pgdata/pg13"?
 pg_ctl: could not start server
         Examine the log output.


Can you share the steps how are you doing the Pgbackrest point in time restore, this will help.

FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists - you still have a running postgresql there. Stop it before trying to replace its files with a backup

@AdelinoSilva Its the normal pgbackrest restore, but only difference is we use kubernetes STS to run the postgresql Cluster. The pgbackrest job would restore the database from the source and then spin up and STS pod in the kubernetes cluster.
